# Why is the variable i in the splice function decremented?

Tags: javascript

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {

    let newArr = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] === elem) {
                arr.splice(i--, 1);
                newArr = arr;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}

console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

I have defined a function, `filteredArray`, which takes `arr`, a nested array, and `elem` as arguments, and `returns` a new array. `elem` represents an element that may or may not be present on one or more of the arrays nested within `arr`. Modify the function, using a `for` loop, to `return` a filtered version of the passed array such that any array nested within `arr` containing `elem` has been removed.

The expected output is [] (an empty array).

Question: Why is the variable `i` in the `splice` function decremented?

Comment: what's the expected output ?

Comment: When you splice, all the elements in the following indexes get shifted back, so what used to be in index 3 is now in index 2 for example, doing `i--` prevents you from skipping an item when one is removed

Comment: @sonEtLumiere The expected output is [] (an empty array).

Answer (score 0):

Because splice updates the original array [in place](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). And in the for loop the condition to check if i < arr.length is calculated on every iteration.

Lets say you have an array of 10 items. In the first iteration arr.length will be 10. After that if you splice and remove 1 item from the array and then try to console.log(arr.length) you will see the length is updated to 9.

If you want to remove all the item in the sub array that is equal to the `elem` you can do that,

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {

    let newArr = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] === elem) {
                arr[i].splice(j, 1);
            }
        }
        newArr.push([...arr[i]])
    }
    return newArr;
}

console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

Comment: for the first iteration, the splice function will be `arr.splice(-1, 1);`? Because 0 - 1 = -1.

Comment: why there will be a `0 - 1`? I am not using `i--` here.

Comment: I'm referring to your explanation to my problem.